# how to use bower sublime text plugin in windows 64 bit

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, bower

I installed `sublime text 3` 64 bit first.

Then i installed `node.js` using `nodejs.msi 64 bit` installer.

Then I used the follwing command to install bower globally in my machine.

```
bower install -g
```

from `node.js` terminal. but i found no traces. It keeps on loading, showing no traces of installation. Then i exited the `nodejs` terminal. Then from the `Windows command prompt` I installed  bower using

```
npm bower install -g
```

After `bower` been installed I installed the `bower-sublime-text` plugin  from `sublime-text` `package control` and used `bower-install` to install a  `bower package` yet no packages has been installed . I tried to install `JQuery` `normalize.css` etc., but found no packages in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of anoying , and i hope someone found a better solution but here we go . In sublime go to Project >  Save Project and save your project in a generic folder like "**Sublime-Projects**" . Now in package control **ctrl+shift+p**  type **bower: configure project**. A **.bowerrc** file will apear change "**components**" to  "**../yourprojectfolder/projectname/components**" and run **bower: install**, select package and voila should work . I found that sublime-bower installs packages in your sublime project/workspace folder ,and it's not such a bad thing but one wants components in actual project folder for easy manipulation and not going through gagilion of folders to reach your needed dependencies .